# How to adjust the parent view's height according to its subviews using auto layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, masonry

I have cutomized a view, whose subviews's height will dynamically change. My intention is to let the view's height adjust to its subviews' height by using auto layout.

Comment: You can achieve it easily. Could you give me your particular instance with a screenshot so that I can help you on that.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do it:
1. Set the view's height constant in storyboard 
2. Import that constraint as an outlet

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *viewHeight;
```

3. As your subViews change height change the value of the outlet

```
self.viewHeight.constant = firstSubView.frame.size.height + secondSubView.frame.size.height;
```

Should work.